# null pointer on javaFX element

Tags: javafx, null

I have the following code and when trying to set the text of the textArea of my fxml I get a null pointer exception. The window appears as it should but the controller is unable to identify the elements within it.

declaration:

```
public TextArea txtArea;
```

This is the controller method body:

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
AnchorPane page = loader.load(getClass().getResource("demo.fxml"));
loader.setController(this);
Scene scene = new Scene(page);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
stage.show();

txtArea.setText("something"); //this is where it crashes -> null pointer
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
            minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="353.0"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
<children>
    <BorderPane prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <center>
            <TextArea fx:id="txtArea" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" prefWidth="200.0" wrapText="true" />
        </center>
    </BorderPane>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You did not show any code that initializes the `txtArea` variable. Are you sure it is initialized?

Comment: because there is not any. I thought elements that come "precoded" within the fxml do not require initialisation

Comment: Is the field annotated with `@FXML`? It is probably best to show all the (relevant) controller code.

Comment: in the side panel of the ide you mean? There is no other relevant code. that is the first and only interraction with this fxml

Comment: Show the declaration of `txtArea`. Probably the issue is that you set the controller *after* calling `load`, but there's no way to really tell unless you show how you have set things up.

Comment: ok I don't know why it worked but I fixed it. Going to post underneath

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in your code. First, you are calling

```
loader.setController(this);
```

*after* you call

```
loader.load();
```

This means there is no controller set on the `FXMLLoader` when it loads the FXML file, so it cannot initialize the controller fields. Switch the order of the calls.

Secondly, you are using the **static** `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` method. Since this is a static method, it won't know anything about the state of the `FXMLLoader` you created, including the controller. You need to set the location, and use the **instance** method `FXMLLoader.load()` with no parameters.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("demo.fxml"));
loader.setController(this);
AnchorPane page = loader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(page);
```

I also strongly recommend making all fields `private`, not `public`. Annotate the fields with `@FXML` to allow injection:

```
@FXML
private TextArea txtArea ;
```

Comment: Tried all of the above with no luck. Trying to narrow down the code to update my question. Is too long to post it all

Comment: Updated with additional fix from your own answer, along with an explanation of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it worked but someone might be able to explain why. I just initialised the FXMLLoader with the .fxml file instead of creating a loader and passing in the load method the resource. I.e.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("demo.fxml"));
loader.setController(this);
AnchorPane page = loader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(page);
```

Comment: Added explanation in my answer.